# The social life of the prophet Muhammad saw and his Sahaba

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sahaba

I can't find any records for their general social behaviour.
What did they used to do when they had time free?
I don't know but I'm sure they had a social life and that's what I want to know.

Comment: IMHO social live is a somewhat broad topic it would be better if you could give your question a kind of focus.

Comment: Well you can start with reading some of the biographies of the Prophet. There should also be some information regarding non-religion related things they do in hadiths.

Answer (score 1):

According to Karen Armstrong, the life of Muhammed is one of the most documented of the major prophets; moreover, his life is unlike to have been very different from those around him; he was a merchant and he married, in these ways I do not think he was in way different from other Arabs.

There is one hadith where one of his wives plays a joke on the Prophet and where he fails to notice that a joke has been played on him, which is part of the joke.

There is another hadith where the prophet walked up a hill with a companion and his companion reached the hill-top before him and where upon he (the companion) thanked Allah; and the prophet rebuked him, saying, 'you can make too much of religion'.

So he went for walks and talked; is this very different from many other men and women in other societies?

Comment: This looks like a partial answer.

Comment: @medi1saif: Well - its a very partial question ...

Comment: It doesn't like the Prophet (SAW) to rebuke a person for thanking Allah. Are you sure it is an authentic story?